# How to see LaTeX output in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, script, plugins, latex

I frequently receive mails with LaTeX text which appear in normal text like

`$frac{(1+cos\theta)^2`

but I want them to be rendered in Mail.app as it would be written in books.

Is there any plugin or some script I can write to do so?

Comment: This is not going to answer your question, but there is a Service called UnicodeIt which would translate say \alpha into α. It works for things like ∫ f(x) dx or √2